# Short story/novella: alien stranded on Earth befriends girl, gives her a device protecting from rape, accidentally goes to the past and dies in Italy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

I remember reading a short story (or novella?) that had a girl who was raised by some terrible relatives because her father went missing. She was befriended by an alien who was stranded on Earth and made a device for her that protected her from rape.

When the alien tried to go home, he ended up inadvertently traveling into the past and ended up dying in Italy, leaving her a large inheritance.

I seem to remember a color being a part of the title. I think the alien was enamored with a color found on Earth that wasn’t common where he was from.

I think I read the story in a collection in the mid-1990s.

Comment: Hi there. Roughly when would this have been published? You might want to [edit] that in, as well as any other memory that [this guide on story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) could remind you of. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I will try to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer on this. I couldn't get this question out of my head because I wanted to share this story with my girlfriend. I googled for every short story collection and looked for titles with a color in them until I found it, "[Perpetuity Blues](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/778166.Perpetuity_Blues_and_Other_Stories)" by Neal Barrett, Jr:

Comment: The story can be read at http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/perpetuityblues.htm